# Can I swap my Saccon Altex calipers with Campagnolo Veloce

Tags: road-bike, brakes

I have a vintage Vitus 787 I'm restoring. The Saccon Altex calipers (http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=e346b35c-c5bb-4f9b-8840-8f58bdbabda0&Enum=117) it came with don't return to their normal position after braking, so I think they need replacing.

I'm thinking about swapping them for these: https://www.wiggle.co.uk/campagnolo-veloce-dual-pivot-brake-caliper-set

I *think* the reach is fine, but I don't know how much to worry about whether my levers will have the correct amount of pull.

Is lever pull generally an issue?

Comment: They probably just need disassembling and lubing.

Answer (score 1):

The pull will be fine if those are the levers you have. You should measure the reach needed by your bike. It's the vertical distance from the center of the brake hole to the center of the brake track. Veloce calipers are 39-49mm.

Doing this with Campy is suboptimal because you won't have brake quick releases anywhere.

Not much can happen to the sort of brake you have to make them truly beyond repair. If normal cleaning/lube and adjustment doesn't do it, they may need their springs bent.

Answer (score 0):

Lever pull usually only an issue when you are using V-brakes or MTB mechanical disk brakes with road levers. Lever pull for road calipers has been standardized for at least the last 30 years. Reach is generally what you need to be concerned about.

[Sheldon Brown Brake Reach](https://sheldonbrown.com/calipers.html#reach) has lot's of good info to ensure you get the right replacement brakes.